# Submitting Form Data which is already existed as object(rails3.22)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ajaxform

How can I submit a form with data taken using GET request from another object? Could anyone help on how to implement this with ajax and create a method in controller?

Comment: `data taken using GET request from another object` what does that mean?

Comment: Iam having an object called entry.It consists of 3 fields.I want to use this object along with my new form fields.So that i can post/submit this data

Comment: Thank you @Gabbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 => For `GET request` use `method: :get`

2 => For Ajax submit use `:remote => true`

```
<%= form_for @object, url: create_object_path, :remote => true, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%=f.text_field :field_1%>
  <%=f.text_field :field_2%>
  <%=f.text_field :field_3%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :another_field, :value @hpentry.HPEntry_Id.present? ? @hpentry.HPEntry_Id : nil%>
  <%=f.submit :submit%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you .But my doubt is iam having hpentry object in another page.It consists  <br/>of name,location,model field data.In view Iam displaying it as <%= @hpentry.HPEntry_Id if @hpentry.HPEntry_Id.present? %>                                                                           I want to submit this object data with my form data.

Comment: @Chaitanya you can use hidden field to send any extra data with form.

Comment: `= f.hidden_field :another_field, :value => @hpentry.HPEntry_Id.present? ? @hpentry.HPEntry_Id : nil`

Comment: @Chaitanya I guess i have given answer that you have mentioned in question, consider this to accepted, before any new question.

Comment: Thank you...It Worked!!! However it shown the following output   "another_field"=>{"{:value=>69652}"=>""}                                                                But it's showing nil after my value